# CherryPy cannot import name safemime

Tags: python, cherrypy

Trying to import safemine from cherrypy

```
from cherrypy import safemime
ImportError: cannot import name safemime
```

Cherrypy is installed with PIP ie.

```
sudo pip install -U cherrypy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [cherrypy-users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cherrypy-users/PmV0CKf8eIk), `safemime` module was removed:

> That module was removed in <del>http://www.cherrypy.org/changeset/2319</del>
>   because its functionality was folded into the new _cpreqbody.py
>   module.

Comment: Thank you, I may have to downgrade to an older version, this is for an existing application.

Comment: By the way, that link is broken.